# How to generate serial number using sql query and update the table with it?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a sql table which looks like :

```
srno | passportnumber|flightnumber
Null | ABC123        |AI-2000
Null | ab3333        |AI-2011
Null | ab565235      |AI-2562
Null | ABC123        |AI-2025
Null | ABC123        |AI-5623
Null | XYZ12334      |AI-5625
```

I need a query to sort them by passportnumber so that repetitive passportnumber rpws are next to eachother and then i want to update the table to insert the serialnumber. 
the result should be something like this :

```
1    | ABC123        |AI-2000
2    | ABC123        |AI-2025
3    | ABC123        |AI-5623
4    | ab3333        |AI-2011
5    | ab565235      |AI-2562
6    | XYZ12334      |AI-5625
```

Comment: sounds like homework. Have you used google?

Comment: This is the third time Arbaaz has posted this question today, with different heading each time. Arbaaz, please stop spamming this site

Comment: I am not spamming, if you read the questions and description carefully you would know that problem is slightly different each time, last time i asked this question i wanted same serial number for the same passport number.

Comment: This is, just, different from the previous question.  But you don't appear to have learned from the previous answers, nor do you appear to be showing much initiative in trying things.  Good questions leave you better informed by the good answers, and able to tackle related problems better.  Or, at the very least, show an attempt that isn't working, and ask about whether the approach is correct, and how to get to a working solution.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

```
;WITH Ranked
AS
(
   SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY passportnumber) row_num
   FROM Tablename
) 
UPDATE Ranked
SET srno = row_num;
```

### [Live Demo](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/86329)

Comment: Yes, your query works! Thanks! But i was wondering if it is possible to change the order of the rows permanently? I do not want to use order by clause every time. Can i alter update or something to permanently sort it by passport

Comment: I had multiple problems and hence multiple questions. The above answer posted by you is perfect for this question.

Comment: I have selected your answer as right answer, but it would be really great if can sort the rows by passportnumber permanently.(which is a seperate question of mine). I do not want to use "order by passport" clause everytime i open the table. I want it to be sorted by passport by default , is that possible?

Comment: @Arbaaz - If I understand well, this is not possible. Because tables always has no specific order. There are stored with no order, they are stored as a `SET`. And this is a standard in all relational databases. You have to add `ORDER BY` to get them ordered.